# Magento2 Products on Category after deployment

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I recently did a release on my magento2 instance on production. Everything looked good for a day, then enabled some configuration and styling went away from all product pages. So I reverted that and rebuilt (di, static files, setup:upgrade, etc). Now all our category pages have no products and seeing an error like the following:

Uncaught exception 'TypeError' with message 'Argument 8 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRenderList::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/xyzcorp.com/releases/20190718151507/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111' in /var/www/vhosts/xyzcorp.com/releases/20190718151507/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRenderList.php:71

I follow the entire stack trace and it is all core magento files. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Error would suggest di compile required

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.  It often happens when you deploy something it throws some random errors like that.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento index:reindex
```

I hope it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: I have done all that. it is part of our deployment process.